# How to find the number of zero elements between sequential non-zero elements

Tags: java

I want to know how many zeros are between sequential non-zero elements in `f` array. This is how I do it:

```
int[] f = new int[]{0,0,3,0,0,1};
int start = 0, end = 0;
for (int i=0; i<f.length; i++)
{
    if (f[i] != 0 && start == 0)
        start=i;
    else if (f[i] != 0 && start != 0)
        end=i;
}
int cnt = (end-start-1)>=0 ? (end-start-1) : (start-end-1);
```

The answer is 2 zeros between 3 and 1.

However, in case of `int[] f = new int[]{0,3,2,0,0,1}` the answer is 3, which is not correct. It should be 2.

Update:
I want to count the number of zeros between LAST left-hand side non-zero element and FIRST right-hand side non-zero element.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code step by step and inspect the variables to see what goes wrong?

Comment: By definition, there are no zeros are between #sequential# non-zero elements -- because they're sequential. You don't need code to solve this.

Comment: @assylias: I guess it's not the problem of debugging. I just don't have a good idea how to count zeros between non-zero elements, if the number of non-zero elements is greater than 2.

Comment: @sam: Thanks, I added -1 to the code.

Comment: There will be many sequences with a variable number of zeroes in between. Please provide how you want the output to be?

Comment: If you debug you will know what is happening and you will be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: @CrakC: I want to count the number of zeros between LAST left-hand side non-zero element and FIRST right-hand side non-zero element.

Comment: So in the case of `{0,0,5,0,0,0,6,0,2,1}`, you would want the answer to be 1 (in between 6 and 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last 0s group, count backwards.

```
private static int countZeros(int[] f) {
    for (int i=f.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(f[i]!=0 && i>0 && f[i-1]==0){
            i--;
            int count=0;
            while(i>=0 && f[i]==0){
                i--;
                count++;
            }
            if(i==0)
                return null;
            else
                return count;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic of detecting when there are changes (from 0 to non-0 and from non-0 to 0 elements) is flawed.

You should look at the `i` and `i-1` elements instead. Consider the following:

- The start index should be when element `i-1` is non-zero and element `i` is 0.
- The end index should be when element `i-1` is 0 and element `i` is non-0 and a start element was found (`start > 0`, this is to take into account the fact that the array can start with 0 and there were no start sequence).

The next thing to consider is that there may be multiple cases of 0's enclosed in non-0's in the array so each time we encounter an end element, we need to add this to a current count.

Putting this into code:

```
private static int countZeros(int[] f) {
    int start = 0, end = 0, cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < f.length; i++) {
        if (f[i-1] != 0 && f[i] == 0) {
            start = i;
        } else if (f[i-1] == 0 && f[i] != 0 && start > 0) {
            end = i;
            cnt += end - start;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Some examples:

```
System.out.println(countZeros(new int[]{0,0,3,0,0,1})); // prints 2
System.out.println(countZeros(new int[]{3,0,0,1})); // prints 2
System.out.println(countZeros(new int[]{3,0,0,1,0})); // prints 2
System.out.println(countZeros(new int[]{3,0,0,1,0,1})); // prints 3
```

Comment: Why is the last one printing `3`?

Comment: @sam There are 2 0's between the first 3 and 1, and another 0 between the two 1. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @sam No because there were no non-0 elements before the first two 0's. So as you said it "count number of zeros between two non-zero numbers "

Comment: Oh. Maybe I misinterpreted the question. I thought zeros between two non-zero only and then break the loop. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Your loops behaviour will have the following effect:

```
for (int i=0; i<f.length; i++)
{
    if (f[i] != 0 && start == 0) //finds only first non-zero in whole array
        start=i;
    else if (f[i] != 0 && start != 0) //finds last non-zero in whole array
        end=i;
}
```

But by taking the difference you include all non-zeros and zeros in the range. So you need a way to count only zeros between these to points, which is hard to add to the first loop because `end` will be changing. The easiest solution is to loop a second time from `start` to `end` and count the zeros:

```
int cnt = 0;
for(int i=start; i<end; i++)
   if(f[i]==0)
      cnt++;
```

This may not the most efficient solution, but it is a way to build upon your existing logic.